# FTP: connect: No route to host error

Tags: linux, networking, ftp, fedora

On my PC I have VMware with two VMs, both are Fedora.

I am trying to use FTP between them, but I'm getting: `ftp: connect: No route to host`

Here the output when I ping from VM1 to VM2:

```
[root@localhost ~]# ping 192.168.20.129
PING 192.168.20.129 (192.168.20.129) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.20.129: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.640 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.20.129: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=1.46 ms
^C
--- 192.168.20.129 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1012ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.640/1.052/1.464/0.412 ms
```

And here when I try to connect via FTP:

```
[root@localhost ~]# ftp 192.168.20.129
ftp: connect: No route to host
```

Comment: Check `system-config-firewall`. Is port 21 open?

Comment: Try `firewall-cmd --state` from the command line and edit your question with the output.

Comment: Sorry, I think `firewall-cmd --list-ports` is the command to check to see if port 21 is open.

Comment: @davidmneedham it says `1025-65535/udp 1025-65535/tcp`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's likely that port 21 is blocked by your firewall.

Run the following commands to open port 21 and restart the firewall service.

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=21/tcp
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-service=ftp
firewall-cmd --reload
```

Comment: I edited my answer to include adding the ftp service

Comment: I disabled the firewall now (don't need it),  now it gives other error: `Connection refused` I think it's because port 21 is closed as you said, I tried `telnet localhost 21` and the output: `telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused` how do I force it to open port 21?

Answer (score 0):

If you get this error *after* connecting successfully (e.g. when you try to list or get files), make sure that the dynamic passive mode ports are open as well in addition to port 21. You can manually define these in vsftpd:

```
#/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf
pasv_max_port=40000
pasv_min_port=50000
```